# How to arrange data in elastic search for log data?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, schema, analytics, kibana

I am working on an application where I need to take huge amount of log-data and store it in ElasticSearch. The data contains information about what product feature a customer has used, time-stamp, customer name, customer location.

I am also using Kibana to query and generate reports from this data.

Currently, I have arranged data in following manner,

- Storing this data in multiple indices where each index has data of one specific feature (used) and customer.
- Another index for customer and location.

I want to minimize the time required search time aggregations and queries can be of following kind:

- Feature vs Customer
- Customer vs Location
- All features vs Customer
- Feature vs Customer vs Time-stamp

Am I doing this right or should I further enhance the structure to minimize search time aggregations?